# Join two table with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'd like to join two tables in my database. It works fine the 'classic' way but there are a bunch of select query in my script, so I'd like to shorten it...

Here is the joint sql:

```
SELECT
    matches.id, matches.start_time, matches.category_id, 
    matches.highl, first_team.tid, first_team.t_name, 
    second_team.tid, second_team.t_name AS ft_name 
FROM matches 
    INNER JOIN teams AS first_team ON matches.first_team_id = first_team.tid 
    INNER JOIN teams AS second_team ON matches.second_team_id = second_team.tid 
ORDER BY matches.id DESC 
    LIMIT 10
```

What I want to achive is something like this, but I don't exactly know how to add all the values I copied above.

```
public function getMatches($table,$conditions = array()){
    $sql = 'SELECT ';
    $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'';
    $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
    if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' WHERE ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
            $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if(array_key_exists("inner_join",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' INNER JOIN '.$conditions['inner_join'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists("on",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ON '.$conditions['on'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists("as",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' AS '.$conditions['as'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit'];
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
        switch($conditions['return_type']){
            case 'count':
                $data = $query->rowCount();
            break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            break;
            default:
                $data = '';
        }
    }else{
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $data = $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    return !empty($data)?$data:false;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Matches</div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Team</th>
          <th>Second Team</th>
          <th>Start Time</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        include 'inc/functions.php';
        $db = new DB();
        $matches = $db->getMatches('matches', array('inner_join'=>'teams'), array('as'=>'first_team'), array('on'=>'matches.first_team_id = first_team.tid'), array('inner_join'=>'teams'), array('as'=>'second_team'), array('on'=>'matches.second_team_id = second_team.tid'), array('order_by'=>'matches.id'));
        if(!empty($matches)){ $count = 0; foreach($matches as $result){ $count++;?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['ft_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['t_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['start_time']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } }else{ ?>
        <tr><td colspan="4">No entry found!</td>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want us to do here? What is your question?

Comment: The values, after SELECT and beforse FROM. How can I add them?   matches.id, matches.start_time, matches.category_id, matches.highl, first_team.tid, first_team.t_name, second_team.tid, second_team.t_name AS ft_name

Comment: genuinely interested - do you actually find that building a query in this manner is easier than compiling it manually?

Comment: By the way, PDO doesn't join your your tables. It just sends the SQL query you wrote to mysql. Removing the tag

Answer (score 2):

With all the honesty, for the life of me I will never ever ever understand, how such wall of PHP arrays

```
array('inner_join'=>'teams'), array('as'=>'first_team'), 
array('on'=>'matches.first_team_id = first_team.tid'), 
array('inner_join'=>'teams'), 
array('as'=>'second_team'), 
array('on'=>'matches.second_team_id = second_team.tid'), 
array('order_by'=>'matches.id'));
```

can be even remotely considered "shorter" than elegant and compact SQL

```
SELECT
    matches.id, matches.start_time, matches.category_id, 
    matches.highl, first_team.tid, first_team.t_name, 
    second_team.tid, second_team.t_name AS ft_name 
FROM matches 
    INNER JOIN teams AS first_team ON matches.first_team_id = first_team.tid 
    INNER JOIN teams AS second_team ON matches.second_team_id = second_team.tid 
ORDER BY matches.id DESC 
    LIMIT 10
```

Let alone the meaningfulness and readability.

Are you talking of saving yourself typing a few SQL keywords like SELECT or FROM? Seriously? Does it really worth making such a mess out of a meaningful and comprehensible SQL?

Comment: Okay, say then I named the function 'getData' and I work with a non-joined table / tables. I simply write for example this: $users = $db->getData('accounts', array('order_by'=>'id'));  ///  function.php: $sql = 'SELECT ';
      $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
      $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;

Comment: So again you are trying to spare a few SQL keywords. Is it really that hard typing them? Especially given your are trading them for PHP code. Why do you want to cripple your SQL and make some limited and gibberish PHP dialect of it?

Comment: I get you and you're propably right. Maybe at the end the 'normal' way proves more useful but for now I'd like to do this way. So, can you help me with it?

Comment: You better think how to make your queries **secure** against SQL injections. **This** would be really worth your (and my) time